# Microsoft Sharepoint Online - total size of the columns in this list exceeds the limit

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Getting the error

Sorry, something went wrong
The column cannot be added because the total size of the columns in this list exceeds the limit. Please delete some other columns first.

When creating new Person type column in Sharepoint Online.

I have checked the total bytes of all columns and they do not exceed the size limit mentioned in docs.
I have also deleted two additional Person type columns from list and one multiline column. The error is not going away.

Comment: Each SharePoint list item can max occupy 8000 bytes per row and 300 Bytes are reserved, so you can use 7700 bytes. And how many items in a view?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've reached the maximum number of lookup limits for a single view. The number of complex columns in a single view cannot exceed 12. While technically you can have more which you can choose to hide and still view your list.

Complex columns include lookup, person/group, managed metadata columns so be aware if you're exceeding this then its better to migrate to CDS or other relational database

[Below link specifies the SharePoint limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fsharepoint-online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498)